# file not found error when I go to user.aspx

Tags: permissions, central-administration

Getting following error when I go to central Admin area and click on Site Actions > Site permission. The page is http://SPServer.com:5600/_layouts/user.aspx. TopNavBar.ascx does exist. btw, we did not edit the application page or masterpage.

= = = here is the error = = = 
The file '/_layouts/_controltemplates/TopNavBar.ascx' does not exist. 
Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 
Correlation ID: 2bba9397-d91a-43cb-8d1e-76ca136435d3 
Date and Time: 6/8/2012 8:53:14 AM

= = = ULS Log = = =
System.Web.HttpException: The file '/_layouts/_controltemplates/TopNavBar.ascx' does not exist.
 at System.Web.UI.Util.CheckVirtualFileExists(VirtualPath virtualPath)
 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile)
 at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile)
 at System.Web.UI.BaseTemplateParser.GetReferencedType(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean allowNoCompile)
 at System.Web.UI.BaseTemplateParser.GetUserControlType(VirtualPath virtualPath)
 at System.Web.UI.MainTagNameToTypeMapper.ProcessUserControlRegistration(UserControlRegisterEntry ucRegisterEntry)
 at System.Web.UI.BaseTemplateParser.ProcessDirective(String directiveName, IDictionary directive)
 at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking a wild guess here, but has anyone changed the user.aspx file in the layouts folder on the SharePoint server?

The link to the TopNavBar.ascx should be ~/_controltemplates/TopNavBar.ascx not /_layouts/_controltemplates/TopNavBar.ascx.

The top part of my User.aspx file looks like the following:

```
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%> <%@ Page Language="C#" DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.UserRoles"       %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="TopNavBar" src="~/_controltemplates/TopNavBar.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="ActionBar" src="~/_controltemplates/ActionBar.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="ToolBar" src="~/_controltemplates/ToolBar.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="wssuc" TagName="ToolBarButton" src="~/_controltemplates/ToolBarButton.ascx" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="wssawc" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Import Namespace= "Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %>
```

Does your's look the same?

Or has anyone deleted the TopNavBar.ascx from the ControlTemplate folder?

Comment: As far I know no should be changing that. Let me open it in notepad++.

Comment: where in 14 hive user.aspx is located? is it the one here C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS

Comment: I replaced the production user.aspx file with dev and now it's fine. It did have a modification date but goes back to 9/30/2011. oh well, it's working now. Thank you Paul